# Use vsprintf with non array as arguments

Tags: php

```
echo vsprintf('%s', 'word');
```

According to manual, second parameter for `vsprintf()` function must be array.

But this works, its normal? this may cause some error sometime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$args` argument is automatically cast to an array:

```
$args = (array)$args;                            // = array('word');
```